# In fusion charts display invalid xml data with german characters 'ö' and 'ü'

Tags: java

With german character `ö` and `ü` its display Invalid `XML` data in `JSP` page.

I have used the `setDataXML()` method to hold result getting by `ajax` call instead `setDataURL()` because `setDataURL()` is taking the action `URL` and we have a long `CSV` URL so it was created problem for us.

But during that we face the problem like if any string found with `%,',&` than it will not render as it consider it as a invalid `HTML`.

After long r&d we found that `FusionChat` expect the value to be encode into `XML` format and than it is encoded by `HTML` encoder.

e.g But with that `URLEncoder` german character gives invalid `XML` error if i remove the `URLEncoder` and then try again its working fine with german character but still found problem with special character `% ' &`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape special character `&` with `&amp;`,

XML not support `&` while parsing you need to escape such character.

Comment: No i have not a problem with special character & or else. Because i already encoded with URLEncoder. My problem is that german character is not working with URLEncoder its gives 'Invalid xml data'. If i try without URLEncoder then german character is working fine.